Spring gateway SetPath filter throws error "Map has no value for 'customerId'" used in new path
I have spring gateway app with this configuration:
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      mvc:
        http-client:
          type: autodetect
        routes:
          - id: getCustomer
            uri: ${services.side-service-uri}
            predicates:
              - Method=GET
              - ExtractJWTTokenClaim=customerId
              - Path=/v1/customers/customer
            filters:
              - SetPath=/api/customer/{customerId}

ExtractJWTTokenClaim is a custom predicate which takes customerId from jwt token and puts it uriVariables using MvcUtils.putUriTemplateVariables. It's logic is very similar to what we can see here
Everything is working fine with the configuration provided above. The problem starts when i want my custom predicate to be called after the Path predicate so when i replace ExtractJWTTokenClaim and Path the filter SetPath throws error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Map has no value for 'customerId'
I debugged the code and found out that everything works fine in my predicate, but this variables are gone when reaching SetPath.
Why does it happen?
